# 404 error after delete index.php in permalinks wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, httpd.conf, permalinks

I wanted to change permalinks in my WordPress blog. I chose /%category%/%postname%/. After changing, I got 404 error. if I add /index.php/%category%/%postname%/ it works nice, however, I don't need such links. My .htaccess is

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I checked my httpd.conf and add such row
`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

It still doens't work without indes.php in my wordpress links

Answer (score 0):

Don't edit .htaccess file, in WordPress go to backend Settings -> Permalinks page where you can manage this setting. check screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I have the same.